# PHP counterpart for jQuery processData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

While transmitting PHP code via jQuery ajax post requests I ran into problems with string quoting. When jQuery's ajax's method's `processData` is not set or set to true, the passed code, according to jQuery manual:

> will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the
>   default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

This leads me to think I should `urldecode()` the input in PHP, but that's not correct, since that's about transforming percent encoded strings back to actual characters, and not about quoting.

I've tried using `stripslashes()` and `stripcslashes()` and both seem to work, but since they are not identical, this leaves me a bit uncertain as to which is the correct way, that will reliably leave me with 100% bitwise identical input?

As a workaround I'm thinking of Base64 encoding the code in javascript before submitting, but this adds possibly unnecessary overhead.

So: What is the correct PHP counterpart to jQuery's `processData`?

**Edit:**
To clarify what's happening, here's an example:

Code input:

```
/** Textfield has the following contents:
 *  <?php
 *  echo 'Hello world!';
 */
var code = $("textarea").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "gateway.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {code : code}
});
```

And in the PHP backend:

```
var_dump($_POST['code']);
/** Output is:
 *  <?php
 *  echo \'Hello world\';
 */
```

Comment: php automatically parses post data, you dont need to do anything. You can see this with a standard html form - your browser will automatically url encode the data, and php with decode it. What this has to do with quotes and slashes, i have no idea

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Steve, I've added a demonstration how the problem manifests itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you have magic_quotes_gpc on, which drives php to escape some characters of GET, POST and COOKIES (especially quotes) automatically. It's very unlikely that the escaping is done in your Javascript.

Have a look at the php-manual:
http://php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

You can disable that feature on server basis and manually in your scripts but that is a bit ugly. The preferable solution is to change your **php.ini** or to search for such option in your hosting providers panel if you don't have access to the ini-file.

Hope i could help

Comment: Ehh... You're absolutely correct of course. I've been playing with so many different servers lately that apparently I'm starting to lose grasp of how everything is configured.